# SQL Server query one table based on conditions in second table

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help a newbie to SQL out please with this situation.

Given a membership database where there can be more than one member per membership account, is it possible to return all records from the membership table where no member (in the membername table) is over a specified age.

The tables look like this:

```
membership.id
membership.membershipnumber

membername.id
membername.membershipnumber
membername.name
membername.age
```

Many thanks

Comment: I would *hope* that you're actually storing date of birth, rather than age. An age column requires constant maintenance, whereas dob should remain fixed (aside from error correction)

Comment: Yes, your correct, this is simpler test on though

Answer (score 1):

There are probably faster methods but this is a straightforward way of doing it.

```
Select membershipnumber 
From membership
Where membershipnumber 
        Not In (
                Select membershipnumber
                From membername
                Where age > @pAge
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select distinct m.membershipnumber
from membership s
inner join (select membershipnumber from membername where age > 18) aux on aux.membershipnumber = m.membershipnumber
```

You can replace `18` by a `@variable`.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking, he's asked for any memberships (groups) that have NO member greater than a certain age.

Comment: @SteveHomer indeed, it's rectified. You still don't need two selects.

Comment: No still not right I think. If you have a membership (group) with 2 members one 17 and one 19 then this will be returned by your query. The OP is asking for a query that would return only the group where ALL members are less than 18 not where SOME members are less than 18.

Comment: @SteveHomer then I don't recall a way of doing avoiding the inner select :(